# Why am I getting duplicate records when using a cursor?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using a cursor to fetch values from a table row by row, perform some calculations and then store the derived values into a temp table. There should be one record in the temp table for each record in the original table (in this case 39 rows). For some reason my temp table ends up with twice the number of rows (78) with the first 39 being the same record repeated 39 times and the subsequent 39 rows being properly calculated.

So for example, the first 39 rows will be the below repeated 39 times:

```
2006-02-28, 1, 12.13, 0.97, 0.038281, 1.0183812
```

And then starting on row 40 it picks up properly

```
2006-03-31, 1.0183812, 50.15, 0.85, 0.054849, 1.016651561
2006-04-30, 1.016651561, 52.34, 0.45, 0.06516981, 1.032151
2006-05-31, 1.032151, 54.10, 0.62, 0.56196189, 1.016651561
```

and so on...

Here's the query:

```
DECLARE @fiscalPeriod smalldatetime,
        @openingUnits float,
        @divPrice money,
        @divFactor float,
        @drip float,
        @endingUnits float


DECLARE divCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT [FiscalPeriod]
      ,[DivPrice]
      ,[DivFactor]
  FROM [dbo].[DividendPricing]
  ORDER BY FiscalPeriod

OPEN divCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM divCursor
INTO @fiscalPeriod, @divPrice, @divFactor

SET @openingUnits = 1
SET @drip = @openingUnits/@divPrice*@divFactor
SET @endingUnits = @openingUnits + @drip

SELECT FiscalPeriod = @fiscalPeriod, OpeningUnits = @openingUnits, DivPrice = @divPrice, DivFactor = @divFactor, DRIP = @drip, EndingUnits = @openingUnits + @drip
INTO #Temp
FROM DividendPricing

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

FETCH NEXT FROM divCursor
INTO @fiscalPeriod, @divPrice, @divFactor

SET @openingUnits = @endingUnits
SET @drip = @openingUnits/@divPrice*@divFactor
SET @endingUnits = @openingUnits + @drip

INSERT INTO #Temp (FiscalPeriod, OpeningUnits, DivPrice, DivFactor, DRIP, EndingUnits)
VALUES (@fiscalPeriod, @openingUnits, @divPrice, @divFactor, @drip, @endingUnits)

END

CLOSE divCursor
DEALLOCATE divCursor

SELECT * FROM #Temp

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Comment: Your initial insert into #Temp (the SELECT INTO) is inserting a row for each row in DividendPricing.  I think you want to remove the "FROM DividendPricing" clause.

Comment: @BoCoKeith That was it, make it an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SELECT ... INTO #Temp operation is inserting into #Temp the same values (from the variables) for every row in DividendPricing table (+39)

Then your loop is going around and inserting each of the remaining rows (+38).

Finally, because you have an INSERT after the FETCH NEXT, you are inserting even though the FETCH NEXT returned no record. (+1)

I am guessing that your SELECT ... INTO #Temp should actually be the same as the INSERT at the end of your loop.

You should re-organise your SQL to fetch the 2nd row prior to the loop, and move the FETCH NEXT to the bottom of the loop.

```
DECLARE @fiscalPeriod smalldatetime,
        @openingUnits float,
        @divPrice money,
        @divFactor float,
        @drip float,
        @endingUnits float


DECLARE divCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT [FiscalPeriod]
      ,[DivPrice]
      ,[DivFactor]
  FROM [dbo].[DividendPricing]
  ORDER BY FiscalPeriod

OPEN divCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM divCursor
INTO @fiscalPeriod, @divPrice, @divFactor

SET @openingUnits = 1
SET @drip = @openingUnits/@divPrice*@divFactor
SET @endingUnits = @openingUnits + @drip

INSERT INTO #Temp (FiscalPeriod, OpeningUnits, DivPrice, DivFactor, DRIP, EndingUnits)
VALUES (@fiscalPeriod, @openingUnits, @divPrice, @divFactor, @drip, @endingUnits)

FETCH NEXT FROM divCursor
INTO @fiscalPeriod, @divPrice, @divFactor

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @openingUnits = @endingUnits
SET @drip = @openingUnits/@divPrice*@divFactor
SET @endingUnits = @openingUnits + @drip

INSERT INTO #Temp (FiscalPeriod, OpeningUnits, DivPrice, DivFactor, DRIP, EndingUnits)
VALUES (@fiscalPeriod, @openingUnits, @divPrice, @divFactor, @drip, @endingUnits)

FETCH NEXT FROM divCursor
INTO @fiscalPeriod, @divPrice, @divFactor

END

CLOSE divCursor
DEALLOCATE divCursor

SELECT * FROM #Temp

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Comment: Good catch on the `INSERT` after the `FETCH NEXT`. The re-ordering gets rid of a final duplicated row. Only thing is by replacing the `SELECT INTO` with `INSERT` the `#Temp` table isn't created and the script fails. Otherwise this works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your initial insert into #Temp (the SELECT INTO) is inserting a row for each row in DividendPricing. I think you want to remove the "FROM DividendPricing" clause.